# Unexpected behavior with multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In the code below, I was expecting the output to be 2 as I'm changing the value of config before assigning function to pool for multiprocessing, but instead I'm getting 5. I'm sure there is a good reason for it, but not sure how to explain it.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 
config = 5

class Test:

  def __init__(self):
    print("This is init")

  @classmethod
  def testPrint(cls, data):
    print(config)
    print("This is testPrint")
    return config

if __name__ == "__main__" :
  pool = Pool()
  config = 2
  output = pool.map(Test.testPrint, range(10))
  print(output)
```

Output

```
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
5
This is testPrint
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what's going on here, but we make some use of Multiprocessing, and we've learned to steer clear of global variables.  A copy is made of the environment at some point via Pickling because you don't have a shared memory environment.  Exactly what's going on with this particular value, I can't say.  What I'll add is to suggest what we've learned...pass all of your shared values very explicitly, both in and especially out of the subprocesses.

Comment: Sounds like @tdelaney's answer is running along the same lines, with more detail.  All good.

Comment: @Steve I was expecting that writing the shared values in the subprocesses going to be messed up but not the reading. Learned a new thing today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new processes are created when you create the pool. After that, changes made to the parent memory space, except for stuff that is passed in a pool function like `.map`, are not seen by the subprocess. Forking systems like linux create copy-on-write views to the parent memory space - and that write results in a unique memory block for the parent, not seen by the subprocess. Spawning systems reimport modules (setting global variables) and then try to pickle/unpickle state for the subprocesses. In both cases, this is completed before the `Pool` class initialization returns to your program.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I verified by changing the value of config before creating the pool. It does print out the desired result.