# How to wait for all multiprocessing.Processes to complete before continuing?

Tags: python, windows, join, multiprocessing

I am learning about Python `multiprocessing` and trying to understand how I can make my code wait for all processes to finish and then continue with the rest of the code. I thought `join()` method should do the job, but the output of my code is not what I expected from the using it.

Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time 

def fun():

    print('starting fun')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('finishing fun')

def fun2():

    print('starting fun2')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('finishing fun2')

def fun3():

    print('starting fun3')
    print('finishing fun3')   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    print('starting main')
    for i in [fun, fun2, fun3]:
        p = Process(target=i)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()  
    print('finishing main')

g=0
print("g",g)
```

I expected all processes under `if __name__ == '__main__':` to finish before the lines `g=0` and `print(g)` are called, so something like this was expected:

```
starting main
starting fun2
starting fun
starting fun3
finishing fun3
finishing fun
finishing fun2
finishing main
g 0
```

But the actual output indicates that there's something I don't understand about `join()` (or `multiprocessing` in general):

```
starting main
g 0
g 0
starting fun2
g 0
starting fun
starting fun3
finishing fun3
finishing fun
finishing fun2
finishing main
g 0
```

The question is: How do I write the code that finishes all processes first and then continues with the code without multiprocessing, so that I get the former output? I run the code from command prompt on Windows, in case it matters.

Comment: Different, but related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64126594/unexpected-behavior-with-python-multiprocessing-pool/64126693#64126693

Comment: You don't have a problem with `.join()`, but with your indentation. See similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53195581/9059420).

Answer (score 1):

**On waiting the `Process` to finish:**

You can just `Process.join` your list, something like

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def func1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('func1')

def func2():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('func2')

def func3():
    time.sleep(3)
    print('func3')

def main():
    processes = [
        multiprocessing.Process(target=func1),
        multiprocessing.Process(target=func2),
        multiprocessing.Process(target=func3),
    ]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But if you're thinking about giving your process more complexity, try using a `Pool`:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def func1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('func1')

def func2():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('func2')

def func3():
    time.sleep(3)
    print('func3')

def main():
    result = []
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        result.append(pool.apply_async(func1))
        result.append(pool.apply_async(func2))
        result.append(pool.apply_async(func3))

        for r in result:
            r.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[More info on `Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

**On why g0 prints multiple times:**

This is happening because you're using `spawn` or `forkserver` to set your `Process` and the `g0` and `print` declarations are outside a function or the `__main__` if block.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods):

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).
>
> (...)
>
> This allows the newly spawned Python interpreter to safely import the module and then run the module’s `foo()` function.
>
> Similar restrictions apply if a pool or manager is created in the main module.

It's basically interpreting again because it's importing your `.py` file as a module.

Comment: The use of a list comprehension like `[p.start() for p in processes]`, which just throws away the list after creating it simply to execute something else multiple times instead of using a regular `for`-loop is both inefficient and generally considered a poor python programming practice by many (including myself).

Comment: You're right, thanks for the feedback. I've edited my response to reflect that.

Comment: Definitely an improvement, IMO.

Comment: If you're calling wait, you probably don't want `async` and can just follow [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction)